# MySQL > Adding extra characters to result of INTO OUTFILE

Tags: mysql, sql, json, function

Sorry for the title, could not think of a better.

So my goal is to write json-formatted text from mysql straight to the file. I've tried to make it few ways:

1) https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_json - using json_array functions

2) using sql:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'pathToFile' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES 
    STARTING BY '['
    TERMINATED BY '],\n'
FROM Table
```

But both cases did not give me what I want.

**Want:**

```
[
   ["1","2","3"],
   ["1","2","3"]
]
```

**Got from json_array functions:**

```
["1","2","3"]
["1","2","3"]
```

**Got from sql:**

```
["1","2","3"],
["1","2","3"],
```

Any ideas how to change sql statement to get result i want to? or maybe any other way to achieve the result?

Comment: That sounds sketchy at best. Wouldn't re-writing using an external script be the way to do this?

Comment: @tadman, for now I'm making editing of my result file, removing last comma and wrapping with additional scopes. But it is not cool, I want to get correct json result from mysql w/o additional workaround

Comment: MySQL is not intended to do this internally. It's just a database. Using a thin scripting layer around it is normally how this kind of problem is solved. Don't think of it as a work-around, think of it as how it works.